Problem to optimize the motion of a spacecraft
I have a problem to optimize the motion of a spacecraft. It starts relative to point O, moving in an undisturbed near-Earth circular orbit with a radius of 6871 km. The gravitational parameter of the Earth is equal to 3.9860044∙10^14 m^3/s^2. The problem is to fly in dt = 86400 seconds from a point in phase space r0 = (10 km, 100 km, -5 km)^T, v0 = (1 m/s, -10 m/s, 3 m/s)^T to the origin, that is, to the point rf = 0, vf = 0. The initial mass of the spacecraft is equal to 1000 kg, the specific impulse of the spacecraft propulsion system is 220 seconds (2157.463 m/s), and the thrust is varied in range from 0.362 to 100 N. I am trying to minimize the propellant mass index to carry out the rendezvous between two spacecraft to solve the problem of orbital transfer and spacecraft rendezvous and docking.
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
 
# Create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()
 
# Time discretization
nt = 101
m.time = np.linspace(0, 1, nt)
 
# Constants
mu = 3.9860044e14
R = 6871e3
Isp = 2157.463
g0 = 9.81
 
# Initial conditions
r0 = np.array([10e3, 100e3, -5e3])
v0 = np.array([1, -10, 3])
rf = np.array([0, 0, 0])
vf = np.array([0, 0, 0])
m0 = 1000
 
# Variables
r = [m.Var(value=r0[i], name=f'r{i}') for i in range(3)]
v = [m.Var(value=v0[i], name=f'v{i}') for i in range(3)]
mass = m.Var(value=m0, name='mass')
thrust = m.MV(value=50, lb=0.362, ub=100, name='thrust')
thrust.STATUS = 1
theta = [m.Var(value=0, lb=-np.pi, ub=np.pi, name=f'theta{i}') for i in range(3)]
 
# Equations of motion
for i in range(3):
    m.Equation(r[i].dt() == v[i])
    m.Equation(v[i].dt() == (thrust * m.cos(theta[i])) / mass - (mu / R**3) * r[i])
 
# Mass flow rate
m_flow = thrust / (Isp * g0)
m.Equation(mass.dt() == -m_flow)
 
# Final conditions
for i in range(3):
    m.fix(r[i], pos=nt-1, val=rf[i])
    m.fix(v[i], pos=nt-1, val=vf[i])
 
# Objective: Minimize the final mass
m.Obj(mass)
 
# Solve the optimization problem
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve(disp=True)
 
# Display results
print(f'Final mass: {mass.value[-1]} kg')
for i in range(3):
    print(f'Final position r{i}: {r[i].value[-1]} m')
    print(f'Final velocity v{i}: {v[i].value[-1]} m/s')
 
# Extract trajectory data
r_data = np.zeros((nt, 3))
for i in range(3):
    r_data[:, i] = np.array(r[i].value)
 
# Plot the trajectory in 3D
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
 
# Plot the trajectory
ax.plot(r_data[:, 0], r_data[:, 1], r_data[:, 2], label='Trajectory')
 
# Plot the Earth as a sphere
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0:np.pi:10j]
x = R * np.cos(u) * np.sin(v)
y = R * np.sin(u) * np.sin(v)
z = R * np.cos(v)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, color='w', alpha=0.3)
 
# Plot the initial and final positions
ax.scatter(r0[0], r0[1], r0[2], color='r', label='Initial Position')
ax.scatter(rf[0], rf[1], rf[2], color='g', label='Final Position')
 
# Labels and legend
ax.set_xlabel('X (km)')
ax.set_ylabel('Y (km)')
ax.set_zlabel('Z (km)')
ax.set_title('Spacecraft Trajectory')
ax.legend()
 
plt.show()

I got results, but I only see the starting and ending points on the graph, but I don't see the trajectory described by the spacecraft leaving the starting point for the meeting point (end point).
Could you help me with that?

The spacecraft isn't able to make progress to the final destination because the time interval is 1 sec. One change is to set the final time to 86400 sec.
m.time = np.linspace(0, 86400, nt)

A couple other changes:

Set a lower bound on mass. Otherwise, the mass goes to zero and a small thrust can send the spacecraft to any location. The lower bound should be the mass of the spacecraft without fuel.

mass = m.Var(value=m0, name='mass', lb=10)


The theta[i] values should be MV types, not variable types. There are no equaions that determine the value of theta[i] so it is a degree of freedom. If there is only one theta[i] value, then set it to FV type.

theta = [m.MV(value=0, lb=-np.pi, ub=np.pi, name=f'theta{i}') for i in range(3)]
for i in range(3):
    theta[i].STATUS = 1
    theta[i].DMAX = 0.1


A hard constraint for the final conditions can prevent the optimizer from finding a feasible solution. Try using the hard constraint m.fix_final() together with a soft constraint m.Minimize() to find the closest solution.

# Final conditions
p = np.zeros(nt); p[-1]=1
final = m.Param(p)
for i in range(3):
    #m.fix_final(r[i], val=rf[i])
    #m.fix_final(v[i], val=vf[i])
    m.Minimize(1e-6*(r[i]-rf[i])**2)
    m.Minimize(1e-6*(v[i]-vf[i])**2)


Try initializing with a better guess value to get a solution that is closer to the optimized solution. This can help the optimizer converge.

# initialize
m.options.COLDSTART = 1
m.solve(disp=True)
 
# optimize
m.options.TIME_SHIFT = 0
m.options.COLDSTART = 0
m.solve(disp=True)

Below is the full script that converges, but needs additional work on tuning to reach the correct final point with the soft objective function.

from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
 
# Create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()
 
# Time discretization
nt = 201
m.time = np.linspace(0, 1400, nt) #86400

# Constants
mu = 3.9860044e14
R = 6871e3
Isp = 2157.463
g0 = 9.81
 
# Initial conditions
r0 = np.array([10e3, 100e3, -5e3])
v0 = np.array([1, -10, 3])
rf = np.array([0, 0, 0])
vf = np.array([0, 0, 0])
m0 = 1000

# Variables
r = [m.Var(value=r0[i], name=f'r{i}') for i in range(3)]
v = [m.Var(value=v0[i], name=f'v{i}') for i in range(3)]
mass = m.Var(value=m0, name='mass', lb=10)
thrust = m.MV(value=50, lb=0.3, ub=100, name='thrust')
thrust.STATUS = 1
thrust.DMAX = 20
theta = [m.MV(value=0, lb=-np.pi, ub=np.pi, name=f'theta{i}') for i in range(3)]
#for i in range(3):
#    theta[i].STATUS = 1
#s    theta[i].DMAX = 0.1

# Equations of motion
for i in range(3):
    m.Equation(r[i].dt() == v[i])
    m.Equation(v[i].dt() == (thrust * m.cos(theta[i])) / mass - (mu / R**3) * r[i])
 
# Mass flow rate
m_flow = thrust / (Isp * g0)
m.Equation(mass.dt() == -m_flow)
 
# Final conditions
p = np.zeros(nt); p[-1]=1
final = m.Param(p)
for i in range(3):
    #m.fix_final(r[i], val=rf[i])
    #m.fix_final(v[i], val=vf[i])
    m.Minimize(1e-6*(r[i]-rf[i])**2)
    m.Minimize(1e-6*(v[i]-vf[i])**2)

# Objective: Minimize the final mass
m.Minimize(mass)

# Solve the optimization problem
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.NODES = 2
m.options.RTOL = 1e-6
m.options.OTOL = 1e-6
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.MAX_ITER = 800

# initialize
m.options.COLDSTART = 1
m.solve(disp=True)
 
# optimize
m.options.TIME_SHIFT = 0
m.options.COLDSTART = 0
m.solve(disp=True)

# Display results
print(f'Final mass: {mass.value[-1]} kg')
for i in range(3):
    print(f'Final position r{i}: {r[i].value[-1]} m')
    print(f'Final velocity v{i}: {v[i].value[-1]} m/s')
 
# Extract trajectory data
r_data = np.zeros((nt, 3))
for i in range(3):
    r_data[:, i] = np.array(r[i].value)

# Plot the trajectory in 3D
fig = plt.figure(0,figsize=(10, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
 
# Plot the trajectory
#ax.plot(r_data[:, 0], r_data[:, 1], r_data[:, 2], label='Trajectory')
 
# Plot the Earth as a sphere
#ue, ve = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0:np.pi:10j]
#xe = R * np.cos(ue) * np.sin(ve)
#ye = R * np.sin(ue) * np.sin(ve)
#ze = R * np.cos(ve)
#ax.plot_surface(xe, ye, ze, color='w', alpha=0.3)

# Plot the initial and final positions
ax.scatter(r0[0], r0[1], r0[2], color='r', label='Initial Position')
ax.scatter(r[0].value, r[1].value, r[2].value, color='b', label='Trajectory')
ax.scatter(rf[0], rf[1], rf[2], color='g', label='Final Position')

# Labels and legend
ax.set_xlabel('X (km)')
ax.set_ylabel('Y (km)')
ax.set_zlabel('Z (km)')
ax.set_title('Spacecraft Trajectory')
ax.legend()

plt.figure(1,figsize=(6,4))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,thrust.value,'r-',label='thrust')
plt.plot(m.time,theta[0].value,'b:',label='theta[0]')
plt.plot(m.time,theta[1].value,'g--',label='theta[1]')
plt.plot(m.time,theta[2].value,'k-',label='theta[2]')
plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.ylabel('MVs')
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,r[0].value,'b:',label='r[0]')
plt.plot(m.time,r[1].value,'g--',label='r[1]')
plt.plot(m.time,r[2].value,'k-',label='r[2]')
plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.ylabel('Position')
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time,v[0].value,'b:',label='v[0]')
plt.plot(m.time,v[1].value,'g--',label='v[1]')
plt.plot(m.time,v[2].value,'k-',label='v[2]')
plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.ylabel('Velocity')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.tight_layout()
 
plt.show()


Another thing to try is to double check the equations. The gravitational term should be only in the radial direction. The circumference of the earth makes it so the trajectory is hard to visualize and has been commented out.
There is a similar problem with the HALE trajectory optimization in gekko that may serve as inspiration for your problem.


Even with these changes made by you, I did not find a solution. The question remains the same: why does the graph with the code presented previously not show the trajectory of the spaceship, but only points?

The points are displayed, but they are close together relative to the plot of the earth and the final value. Optimization with trigonometric functions can be challenging as well as end-point hard constraints. I recommend an approach that uses soft final conditions (objective function based) versus fixed-endpoint.

The last code doesn't work "Solution Not Found",  74 m.solve(disp=True).

I worked on it a little more and got a solution that is closer to an optimal solution. You may need to work on it more. I'll modify the answer.
